# Increasing limit of EC2 webserver httpd with php-fpm

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-ec2, server, webserver

Our webserver can only support 300 Concurrent Users (CCU)
We're using AWS EC2 with instance type of t3a.2xlarge and using Amazon Linux 2
Our webserver is httpd and use php-fpm as Server API
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To increase the number of concurrent connections, add the following lines to **httpd.conf**:

```
ServerLimit 1000
MaxClient 1000
```

Comment: What about php-fpm?

I'm using php-fpm as Apache Server API will editing httpd.conf enough?